# How do I keep a specific window on top of others?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, window-manager

I used to use [PowerMenu](http://www.abstractpath.com/powermenu/) to be able to keep a specific window on top.  But it does not work on 64 bit versions of Windows 8 (or 7 for that matter).

Is there something similar that will do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

You should try [DM2](http://dm2.sourceforge.net/)

Works for 32bit and 64bit on windows 7